# app-drawer malfunctions when opacity is set in main content in Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, app-elements

Setting the `opacity` property on main content causes the content to bleed through the `app-drawer` when the drawer is opened. (I assume this is a bug, not a feature?) What is the best solution or workaround?

[Here is the link to the issue filed on Github.](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/503)

#### Expected outcome

I expect the `app-drawer` to opaquely cover all the main content. Even when the main content has the `opacity` property set in the CSS as follows.

```
<style>
  #main {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
</style>
```

#### Actual outcome

The text in the main content appears in front of the drawer when the drawer is opened. See below screen shot.

[image]

#### Live Demo

[Here is the Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iOwrOqjdNuj3JNhMPWaO?p=preview). *(If using Safari, view demo in Chrome instead.)*

#### Steps to reproduce

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.0.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="my-drawer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-drawer></my-drawer>
</body>

</html>
```

my-drawer.html

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">

<dom-module id="my-drawer">

  <template>
    <style>
      #main {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
    </style>

    <app-header reveals>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="_toggleDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>Title</div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <app-drawer id="drawer" opened={{drawerOpened}} tabindex="0">
      <div>I am inside drawer</div>
    </app-drawer>

    <div id="main">
      My "opacity" property makes me "bleed" through the drawer
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyDrawer extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {
        return 'my-drawer';
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'my-drawer'
          }
        };
      }

      _toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerOpened = !this.drawerOpened;
      }

    }

    customElements.define(MyDrawer.is, MyDrawer);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

#### Browsers Affected

- Chrome
- All tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is using the [app-drawer-layout](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-drawer-layout):

Wrap `app-drawer` and `div` using `app-drawer-layout`. Add `slot="drawer"` in `app-drawer` so that the wrapper element will know it is the drawer element.

Modified plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/akTqpcmGzODgZ0gNAWnj?p=preview

Changes in the code:

```
<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer slot="drawer" id="drawer" opened={{drawerOpened}} tabindex="0">
    <div>I am inside drawer</div>
  </app-drawer>
  <div id="main">
    My "opacity" property makes me "bleed" through the drawer
  </div>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to add a `z-index: 1` style attribute to my `<app-drawer>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Actual code for <strike>accepted</strike> @Neilujd's answer:

my-drawer.html

```
<style>
  #main {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  app-drawer {
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
```